# emacs24 losing window frame on startup

Tags: linux, emacs, window, emacs24

I just updated Fedora 18 on my Dell laptop.

Now when I start emacs in X, it first appears normal, but once I mouse over the window, it suddenly loses all the window manager frame stuff, and this also loses the emacs echo area at the bottom.

Startup image:

[image]

After mouse over:

[image]

I can move around the window by clicking on the top area to the right of the "File Edit options..." menu area, but no resize or close or forward functionality.

When I do meta-anything, the echo area appears to be below what is displayed, so it is rather difficult to do much without this.

Nothing seems to bring back the window frame stuff.

I am running emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.4)
 of 2013-07-14 on buildvm-05.phx2.fedoraproject.org
KDE 4.10.5

$ uname -a
Linux my-machine 3.10.10-100.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 29 20:13:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I suggest to build a fresh emacs from source.

Comment: Also, when I use the menu in emacs to open a new frame, the new frame has the same behaviour: first it is OK; then it loses frame stuff on mouse over...

Comment: I rebuilt from source (GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2013-09-12 on onottr624241) and all is back to normal. I will uninstall the updated version and go with my built-from-source version.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are starting Emacs with no init file, i.e., `emacs -Q`, right?  If so, then this is a bug. Please report it in that case: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

If you see the problem *not* with `emacs -Q` but only with your startup file, then find out which part of your init file introduces the problem.  To do that, bisect the file recursively (comment out 1/2, then 1/4, then 1/8,...).  You can use command `comment-region` to comment or (plain `C-u`) uncomment large sections of the buffer.